# Finding solutions to the differential equation if you know isoclines?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, initial-value-problems

> Consider the function $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y-1$. Sketch isoclines for
>   $k=0, 2, 4$ on a grid for $x, \, y \in [-5, 5].$ Hence, construct a
>   slope field and sketch the solution curve satisfying $y(0)=1$.

I equated the derivative to the values of $k$ and obtained the following values for the isoclines:

$$y=-x^2+1$$
$$y=-x^2+3$$
$$y=-x^2+5$$

I graphed the isoclines (and the slope field) using Geogebra:

[image]

They indeed connect points having the same slope of the parent function.

But the question requires me to graph the isoclines and **hence** create the slope field (I wouldn't have Geogebra in class :) ). So assuming that the only thing we have on the graph above are the parabolas (and no slope field), how could we create the slope field from the isoclines alone and hence find the solution satisfying the conditions?

The answer, according to my textbook, is this function:

[image]

Comment: I copied the question as it was stated but I assumed that $k$ is a specific value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I think I figured it out - the value of $k$ is simply the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for a given isocline. So I can graph the "bars" on each of the three isoclines and hence determine the shape of the curve passing through (0, 1). This is the right method, right?

Comment: Let's consider the $y=-x^2+5$ isocline. The bars lying on this curve will represent where the original curve has gradient equal to 4, and of course, the bars will be more sloping that those lying on, say, the middle parabola. So based on those bars, and knowing that $y(0)=1$, I can find the shape (albeit quite inaccurate because of the small number of bars) of the solution curve. I graphed this on paper and it seems to give the curve as provided by the textbook answer. Am I doing something wrong?